# Fixing a non-fast forward git error

Tags: git

I'm trying to push my local changes on a remote branch and I get this error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://test@test.com'
```

After reading SO regarding this topic I tried `git stash`, `git pull` which displayed that current branch is up to date, followed by `git stash pop` and `git push`, but the error persists.

What else can I do to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: First `git fetch` to fetch the current state, then `git rebase` or `git merge`

Comment: What do you do between `git stash pop` and `git push` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I have a commit that I want to push. I used stash just to hide a changed file that I don't want to commit yet.

Comment: What does `git status` yield?

Comment: `git pull` should fail in such case, you should rebase/merge your changes manually

Comment: Can we guide me into doing this?

Comment: @crea1, right now is says: "nothing to commit, working directory clean".

Comment: @Cosmin sure, but you need to provide more details, as it's curently written, it's hard to tell what is the state of the repository

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, tell me please what do you need to know? As I wrote before, `git status` shows  "nothing to commit, working directory clean".

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki it also says that "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit."

Comment: @Cosmin so you are tracking the origin/dev branch, while trying to push changes to master. checkout to master branch (`git checkout master`), then `git fetch`, then `git status`, see what is the state of your local master branch

Comment: @Cosmin and if you don't want to change the local master branch, but instead you want to push changes from a local dev branch to origin's dev, then just execute `git push origin dev:dev`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, I don't want to change the local master branch, so I went with `git push origin dev:dev` and it seems that's working. Thanks, mate!